# Centralised python Script that configures multiple machines via SSH

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I want to have a python script that automates the configuration of a set of Machines.
let's assume that:

- We have 3 ubuntu machines: **M1**, **M2** and virtual machine **VM**
  installed on M2.
- M1 can reach M2 via SSH
- M2 can reach VM via SSH

For now, I have a bash script stored locally on each machine (m1.sh, m2.sh, and vm.sh).

- To configure M2 from M1 I run this on m1.sh: `ssh M2 "bash m2.sh"`
- To configure VM from M2 I run this on m2.sh: `ssh VM "bash vm.sh"`

Is there any possible way to have a centralised python script that runs only on M1 without having to have a script on each machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you a lot for your help.

I have solved my problem by setting up some Forwarding rules as described  [here](https://aboullaite.me/kvm-qemo-forward-ports-with-iptables/).

Paramiko is the Library I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want to configure and if you are strictly limited to Python you could use [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) and execute commands from M1.  Alternatively you could use [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) to configure and manage the machines.

Answer (score 1):

The [Fabric library](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/) is designed for exactly this use case. It is built on top of the Python SSH library, Paramiko, and provides a simple way of running Python remotely without having to copy scripts around.